# Objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

```
const sun_descr = document.getElementById("sun_descr");
const merc_descr = document.getElementById("merc_descr");
const venus_descr = document.getElementById("venus_descr");         

ReactDOM.render(<Planet name="Sun" desctiption="the star..."/>, sun_descr);   
ReactDOM.render(<Planet name="Mercury" desctiption="the smallest..."/>, merc_descr);            
ReactDOM.render(<Planet name="Venus" desctiption="the second..."/>, venus_descr);
```

I want to simplify this strings by replase, for example, Sun and sun_descr, elements of object

```
var planets = {
                Sun: sun_descr,
                Mercury: merc_descr,
                Venus: venus_descr
            };
```

How in React get access to key and value?

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/zg3mj40k/

Comment: `planets.Sun` to access `sun_descr` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const planets = [
   { key: 'sun', id: 'sun_descr', component: <Planet name="Sun" desctiption="the star..."/>},
   { key: 'mercury', id: 'merc_descr', component: <Planet name="Mercury" desctiption=""/>},
   { key: 'venus', id: 'venus_descr', component: <Planet name="Mercury" desctiption=""/>},
];


planets.forEach(function(planet) {
  const { component: Component, id } = planet;
  ReactDOM.render(
    Component, 
    document.getElementById(id)
  );
});
```

Here is an implementation of this https://codesandbox.io/s/n712yj5v4 Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use . operetor to access to object console.log(obj.key)

in case of array like

```
let arr = [{key : value},{key : value}];
```

then you can use forEach,map funtion to traverse in react as per your need